# How can I get values in new column based on other column group by columns?

Tags: r

I am trying to get column `desired_output` which consists of values based on `value` column group by `grp_1` & `grp_2`

i.e if the values in `value` column having unique values then values should be `NA`'s

if values repeats more than any value then entire group will be that repeated value

if values repeats equal times  then entire group will be that MAX number value

```
grp_1 = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A")
 grp_2 = c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","e","e","e","e")
 value =c(1,2,3,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,1,2,4,4,1,3,3,3)
desired_output =c(3,3,3,3,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3) 

 df = data.frame(grp_1,grp_2,value,desired_output)
```

I have been struck after getting repeated values count

```
func <- function(x) { 
  unlist(lapply(rle(x)$lengths, seq_len))
  
}  

df <- group_by(df,grp_1,grp_2)
df_1 <- mutate(df, common=as.numeric(func(value)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone likes `data.table`

```
data.table::setDT(df)

df[,desired_outcome:= max(value[duplicated(value)]), by=c("grp_1","grp_2")
  ][is.infinite(desired_outcome),desired_outcome:=NA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(modeest)
final_df <- df %>%
  group_by(grp_1,grp_2) %>%
  mutate(desired_output = ifelse(n()==length(unique(value)),
                                 NA,
                                 ifelse(length(unique(table(value)))==1,
                                        max(value),
                                        mlv(value, method='mfv')[['M']]))) %>%
  data.frame()
final_df
```

Output is:

```
   grp_1 grp_2 value desired_output
1      A     a     1              3
2      A     a     2              3
3      A     a     3              3
4      A     a     3              3
5      A     a     4              3
6      A     b     1             NA
7      A     b     2             NA
8      A     b     3             NA
9      A     b     4             NA
10     A     c     1              2
11     A     c     1              2
12     A     c     2              2
13     A     c     2              2
14     A     d     1              4
15     A     d     2              4
16     A     d     4              4
17     A     d     4              4
18     A     e     1              3
19     A     e     3              3
20     A     e     3              3
21     A     e     3              3
```

```
#sample data
structure(list(grp_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    grp_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("a", 
    "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("grp_1", 
"grp_2", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```